# Using Reflection to call a method of a property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What I'm trying to do is call the method of a property, using Reflection. I have the original Control (a ComboBox), the PropertyInfo of the property (ComboBox.Items) and the name of the method (ComboBox.Items.Add). I've tried the code below to get, alter, set - but it doesn't work because `Items` doesn't have a setter.

```
PropertyInfo p  = controlType.GetProperty(propertyName); // gets the property ('Items')
MethodInfo m    = p.PropertyType.GetMethod(methodName); // gets the method ('Items.Add')
object o        = p.GetValue(newControl, null);         // gets the current 'Items'

m.Invoke(o, new object[] { newValue });                 // invokes 'Add' which works
p.SetValue(newControl, o, null);                         // exception: 'Items' has no setter
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you're interested in making calls like this via reflection easier and are using C# 4, you might want to wrap this reflection functionality in a DynamicObject.  I've written a post about how to do that here: http://mattmc3.blogspot.com/2011/03/fun-with-dynamicobject-and-making-net.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That was quick... I changed the Invoke line to...

```
m.Invoke(p.GetValue(newControl, null), new object[] { newValue });
```

...and it worked :P

Comment: I absolutely love when people find the answers and then post how they solved their own problems. I wish more people did this.

Comment: How did this change work? Can you explain a bit as to what was going wrong?

Comment: @PavanManjunath I'm not entirely sure I'm afraid. It's possible I was boxing the result of `GetValue` by implicit cast to `object` which `Invoke` could not unbox.

Answer (score 5):

@acron, Thanks for providing a great question and answer. I want to extend your solution for a slightly different scenario for anyone looking in the future.

Facing a similar problem in the ASP.NET world I was trying to find a common way to load either a **System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.DropDownList** OR a **System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect** While both of these have an "Items" property of type "ListItemCollection", with a corresponding "Add" method, they do not share a common interface (*as they SHOULD... hey Microsoft...*) so that casting can be used.

The additional challenge that your solution didn't provide for is the overloading of the Add method.

Without the overloads your line:
`MethodInfo m    = p.PropertyType.GetMethod(methodName);`
works just fine. But, when the Add method is overloaded an additional parameter is called for so that the runtime can identify which overload to invoke.

`MethodInfo methInfo = propInfo.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add", new Type[] { typeof(ListItem) });`

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting indicates that the property in question is read only.   There is no set method defined.   You will not be able to set the value for the property without a setter.

Post back with the name of the property or more context and we may be able to give you a better answer or an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I realise it's because there is no setter. My code was just as an example of what I'd tried. Also, the name of the property is in my post -- ComboBox.Items. It's a ComboBox-specific ObjectCollection.