# How to DRY out this code

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am integrating with Quickbooks Desktop using their SDK. I want to build a generic Item list. Their general, top level item query brings back all items (as type `IORItemRet`) and then has different item sub-types within the top level Item. These sub-types do not inherit from a base Item class so I have to look at each returned item, use a switch statement to determine its type, then map that specific type's properties to my generic QuickbooksItem class.

As you can see below, the code is quite redundant. I'd like to be able to encapsulate the common property type settings of ListID and Name, if at all possible.

Any ideas to DRY this code out? I guess at a minimum I could create a function that accepts `(ref qbItem, string ListId, string Name)` and call it in each `case`...but that's still quite damp...I was hoping for something a bit DRYer.

```
public static QuickbooksItem ConvertQueryResponseToClass(IORItemRet itemRet)
{
    var itemType = itemRet.ortype;
    var typeTest = itemRet.Type;

    QuickbooksItem qbItem = new QuickbooksItem();

    switch (itemType)
    {
        case ENORItemRet.orirItemServiceRet:
            var itemService = itemRet.ItemServiceRet as IItemServiceRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemService.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemService.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.Service;
            break;

        case ENORItemRet.orirItemInventoryRet:
            var itemInventory = itemRet.ItemInventoryRet as IItemInventoryRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemInventory.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemInventory.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.Inventory;
            break;

        case ENORItemRet.orirItemNonInventoryRet:
            var itemNonInventory = itemRet.ItemNonInventoryRet as IItemNonInventoryRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemNonInventory.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemNonInventory.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.NonInventory;
            break;

        case ENORItemRet.orirItemOtherChargeRet:
            var itemOtherCharge = itemRet.ItemOtherChargeRet as IItemOtherChargeRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemOtherCharge.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemOtherCharge.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.Other;
            break;

        case ENORItemRet.orirItemSalesTaxRet:
            var itemSalesTax = itemRet.ItemSalesTaxRet as IItemSalesTaxRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemSalesTax.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemSalesTax.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.SalesTax;
            break;

        case ENORItemRet.orirItemSalesTaxGroupRet:
            var itemSalesTaxGroup = itemRet.ItemSalesTaxGroupRet as IItemSalesTaxGroupRet;
            qbItem.Id = itemSalesTaxGroup.ListID.GetValue();
            qbItem.Name = itemSalesTaxGroup.Name.GetValue();
            qbItem.ItemType = ItemTypes.SalesTaxGroup;
            break;
    }

    return qbItem;
}
```

Comment: You *might* be able to do something with Reflection for the properties that are the same on all types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379730/using-reflection-to-call-a-method-of-a-property

Comment: So *all* these types declare and implement the same type of members with the same name (ListID, Name), but they all do that without sharing a common base class?

Comment: Sounds like something QuickBooks would do.

Comment: Some combination of the adapter and facade patterns would allow you to introduce an interface to represent the properties that are common to each of QB's interfaces, but in this case I'm not sure it really gets you anything apart from more code.

Comment: This seems rather open ended and may be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Fun challenge! Up-voted because I love DRYing out my code.  I'm thinking...

Comment: @Amit that is correct.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, just because you like a given type of activity doesn't mean that it's necessarily a good question for Stack Overflow. Open-ended code review questions are explicitly off-topic for SO - questions are expected to be, at least to some degree, about a specific and definitively answerable question. Please don't upvote off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a way to test it, but something like this should work:

```
var itemType = itemRet.ortype;
var typeTest = itemRet.Type;

QuickbooksItem qbItem = new QuickbooksItem();

PropertyInfo ListIdProperty = typeTest.GetProperty("ListID");
MethodInfo ListValueMethod = ListIdProperty.GetMethod("GetValue");

qbItem.Id = (int)ListValueMethod.Invoke(ListIdProperty.GetValue(itemRet, null), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a lib like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map each type to your QuickbooksItem class.

This way you don't need to write the reflection code yourself.

Comment: I love Automapper, but unless it has changed recently, he'd need to manually create a mapping for each type, so it still wouldn't be very DRY.

Comment: True, but i believe placing the mappings on a config file makes the code cleaner

Comment: You can create the map and as long as the property names match it will automatically map them without having to specify them individually